# HTML Email not displaying correctly for Godaddy web based mail

Tags: php, email

I am using the following PHP code to send out an email.  I've tested in Outlook and other places and everything comes through correctly.  However if I send the email to a person using a Godaddy web based email viewer it has 2 problems:

- The FROM email address does not display
- Instead of showing the HTML email it shows the HTML code

This has been verified with multiple godaddy based accounts on multiple machines and browsers.

Here is the code I am using to send the email:

```
//build and send the email      
    $to = $email;
    $subject = 'Confirm your subscription';
    $message =( "<html>\r\n");
    $message .=( "<head>\r\n");
    $message .=( "<title>Confirm</title>\r\n");
    $message .=( "</head>\r\n");
    $message .=( "<body>\r\n");
    $message .=( "<h2>Thank You for registering</h2>\r\n");
    $message .=( "<p>To complete your registration, please click the link below.</p>\r\n");
    $message .=(" <p><a href=\"http://www.site.com/confirmation.php?confirm=$visitor_hash\">Click here to confirm your interest.</a></p>\r\n"); 
    $message .=( "</body>\r\n");
    $message .=( "</html>\r\n");

    $headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
    $headers .= "From: Site<info@site.com>\r\n";
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After much searching, posting and tweaking I found a solution.  I found this on the page for the PHP Mail function, in the user comments.

I changed these 3 lines from:

```
$headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
$headers .= "From: Site<info@site.com>\r\n";
```

To

```
$headers  ='"MIME-Version: 1.0' . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1' . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= 'From: Site<info@site.com>' . PHP_EOL;
```

And that fixed the problem.

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 0):

A properly-built HTML email is actually a MIME email, which you're not building. A mime-version header is not enough. Try using [Swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org) or [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com), both of which let you build multi-part emails effortlessly

Comment: I don't have any options for installing on this server, I have to use what is htere.  Any thoughts on how to properly format and send this email?