# php Mail() and Outlook

Tags: php, email, outlook

I have the following code:

```
    $subject = "Test Email";
    $from = "noreply@bob.com";
    ini_set("sendmail_from", $from);
$message = "<html><body bgcolor=\"#DCEEFC\"> 
                Hello<br><br>
                This is a <b>test</b> email.
                <br><br><hr>
                <a href=\"\">Click Here</a>     
                <br><br><hr>
                <br><br>
                Thank you for your time,<br><br>
            </body></html>";

    $headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n"; 
    $headers .= "From: " . $from . "\r\n";
    mail($mail, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

However, when I send the email to myself, I see all the code in Outlook.  If i send it to someone else, They see the HTML. If i send it to my hotmail, they see the HTML.

Is this a problem with my outlook (2007), if so, what is it, or can I do something in the email to guarantee it being displayed properly?

Please help!

Comment: If you see HTML tags in both Hotmail and Outlook then there is a problem with your code, if you only see HTML tags in Outlook then it is likely that there are some Outlook settings wrong.

Comment: Do you have an idea as to which?

Comment: Which setting or what is wrong with your code?

Comment: Which setting, The problem is then I cannot make sure everyone has this setting turned on.  Which means it is a gamble as to who see's what.

Comment: Mostly people will have it on these days. Maybe you should include the encoding? See Example 4 in http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the problem:

[HTML Email not displaying correctly for Godaddy web based mail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7032621/html-email-not-displaying-correctly-for-godaddy-web-based-mail)

Changed:

```
$headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n"; 
$headers .= "From: " . $from . "\r\n";
```

to:

```
$headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "From: Site<$from>" . PHP_EOL;
```

Thanks for all your help guys!
:)

Answer (score 2):

Try to reorder the header. I remember having the same problem a while ago and it worked after I used the following headers:

```
    $headers = "From: " .$from. "\r\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\r\n";
```

I would recommend though to use a [ready-to-go php mailer class](http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/) - it makes life much easier.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you have your outlook set to display messages in plain text, no matter the format they are sent in.

Go into your outlook prefs and change it to view the messages in the format that they arrive in.

Comment: Other emails read fine in HTML though? I cannot seem to find that setting in the preferences.