# Hotmail.com strips out formatting and hyperlinks from HTML message

Tags: outlook, formatting, strip, hotmail

I'm struggling to figure out how to defeat this process on Hotmail.com.

When I send an e-mail using a PHP script (and PHPMailer libraries, using Sendmail), recipient viewing the message from Hotmail.com gets a very bare message. Images are there, but all of the HTML formatting (styles, attributes, hyperlinks) is stripped away. Not even the `<td>` attributes remain (such as `colspan`, `cellpadding`, etc).

However, when I send the exact same message directly from a regular mail client (or webmail interface), all formatting and styling is preserved intact.

My PHP script sends a customised HTML message to a group of recipients, but it does it one by one (customising parts of the message for each recipient).

It appears that Hotmail doesn't seem to trust my server with the messages and is removing attributes and links as a security precaution. However, there is no way for receiving user to override this. Adding the sender to the whitelist does nothing. I have posted this on a Microsoft forum, without much success. I'm hoping someone here might have fought with the same problem and found a solution, or at least work-around.

I tried various things. I put a time delay of a few seconds between sending of two messages, thinking that Hotmail doesn't like mass mailing, and if two or more messages arrive from same sender at the same time, it will activate this blocking. It didn't help. I tried using SMTP script, sending the message through g-mail's SMTP server. Same problem -- stripped-out formatting.

[update]: I have even tried using Microsoft's own SMTP servers for hotmail, using a valid outlook.com user account to send (from that PHPMailer script). When viewed through hotmail.com web interface, the message is still stripped of all formatting and links.

Meanwhile, when these problem messages are viewed through a mail client (iOS, OSX, Windows, Android, MS Outlook), all is perfectly fine. [/update]

Right now, my work-around is pasting a long URL for this one important link that I want users to use, for recipients who have 'hotmail' or 'outlook' or 'live' in their e-mail address.

Any creative thoughts?

[update 2]After a lot of tinkering, I was able to re-format the message so that at least some of the formatting is preserved, so now, I got `<table>` tags to work. What's weird is, `<bgcolor>` also works, but `<center>` doesn't, nor do any css style attributes (neither to `<tr>`, nor to `<td>` or `<table>` itself). Fortunately, I now have `<a href>` tags working properly, so the links are functional again. I have basically given up on the whole thing and have developed a separate bare-bones template only for hotmail/outlook recipients.

Frustrating![/update 2]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is still an issue for you but since I didn't find ANY resources around that matter I thought it was useful to post it here.

I had the same problem and I figured it was that my links were dummies (only `href="#"`) and that outlook stripped them (whereas gmail rewrites the href).

Apparently if there isn't a valid `href` tag, it strips the link, even if it's been used just for cosmetic.

I would advice not to use them for anything else than links (obviously).

Hope it'll help.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but it didn't help in my case.

Comment: Well maybe it has something to do with the headers like [in this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11757937/php-mail-and-outlook) where the problem was newline characters. Maybe try sending it through [putsmail](http://putsmail.com) ?
It's really wierd that it's only parts of the html that gets modified.
Is the result the same in gmail web client ?

Comment: I'll test in putsmail, but I doubt there would be any red flags. G-mail recipients receive complete, unedited HTML, as do pretty much all others. The only ones where this weird filtering occurs are Microsoft-hosted webmail users (hotmail.com, outlook.com, etc). Opening the same message in another client (desktop, mobile, non-MS web-based interface, such as squirrelmail) shows untouched HTML.